# Backing out of a job contract while waiting for a contract with another company

Tags: contracts, contractors, canada

(The positions discussed are all contractor positions) - 
Canada

I already signed a contract for a PT offer with Company A about a week ago. It states that the agreement can be terminated with 6 weeks notice.

The orientation for this position is supposed to be tomorrow afternoon. This morning, I got a call from Company B who offered me a FT position that I did not interview for (I was only interviewing for PT positions at this time). I will be accepting this position, but this means I will have to back out of my contract with Company A.

Due to certain circumstances, Company B may not be able to get me the contract immediately, with the likelihood of getting the contract after the orientation day for Company A.

I think I should let Company A know as soon as possible that I will be rescinding my acceptance of their offer, but some people have suggested that I wait to get the contract before letting Company A know. However, this would mean I will be wasting Company A's time by attending their orientation tomorrow when I know I'm going to be accepting another offer.

What are your suggestions?

Comment: What does the contract say? We can't tell you about legal issues with backing out of the contract since we never read it.

Comment: If you have signed a contract, then you have entered into a legally binding agreement with company A. What is the notice period in your contract with them? Is there any chance that a start date with company B would be far enough out that you could give company A sufficient notice under your contract?

Comment: @delinear It states that the agreement can be terminated with 6 weeks notice, but I haven't started working for Company A yet. An orientation is scheduled for tomorrow, but the official start date is next week for Company A. The position for Company B starts next week or in 2 weeks at most.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I agree. That is my ideal situation, but waiting would mean I would attend the orientation for Company A and use up more of their time when I know I'm going to be accepting another offer.

Answer (score 1):

> I think I should let Company A know as soon as possible that I will be
>   rescinding my acceptance of their offer, but some people have
>   suggested that I wait to get the contract before letting Company A
>   know. However, this would mean I will be wasting Company A's time by
>   attending their orientation tomorrow when I know I'm going to be
>   accepting another offer.
>
> What are your suggestions?

Since you now said that you "know I'm going to be accepting another offer" the right thing to do is to notify Company A immediately. (Normally I'd suggest waiting until you actually have an offer, but apparently you have already decided.) Tell them that if this full-time offer comes through, you plan to accept it. And if your plan is to leave your part-time contract without waiting the required 6 weeks, you can tell them that as well.

That let's them cancel your orientation if they so choose, or continue on with your orientation if they prefer. Almost certainly they will do the former.

The worst that can happen is that Company A tells you to leave and Company B changes their mind for some reason and you don't actually get their offer. In that case, you'll need to look for a Company C elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Integrity aside, you need to look out for #1 (you)

Also, until you have signed contract , nothing is closed.

But, ultimately, its your decision

Comment: *I signed a contract for a PT offer with Company A about a week ago.* The OP has signed **a** contract.

Comment: Yes, with Company A for part time.
Company B - full time - no contract as of yet.

As i said before, he should not see Company B as employer until he get and sign the papers

Comment: Chances are Company A will just cut their losses and nothing will come of it, but there's always a possibility OP could be sued for breach of contract. If they consider that a risk, they should seek legal advice, however I agree that ultimately they need to consider their own needs first and foremost and it would be silly to pass up a better opportunity in favour of a lesser one.